# Ошибка с RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Собственно проблема следующая. Есть активность которая сначала загружает первый фрагмент:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalogs);

    initFragments();
}

private void initFragments() {
    CatalogsFragment fragment = new CatalogsFragment();
    fragment.setListener(this);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

В самом фрагменте я использую RecyclerView

```
RecyclerView mCatalogsRecyclerView;

MyStorage mStorage;

ArrayList<Catalog> mCatalogs;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_catalogs, container, false);

    mCatalogsRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.catalogs_recyclerview);
    mCatalogsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3));


    mStorage = MyStorage.newInstance(getActivity());

    setupUI();

    return view;
}

private void setupUI() {
    mCatalogs = mStorage.getCatalogs();

    Log.d(TAG, "setupUI() called");

    if (mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new CatalogsAdapter(mCatalogs, this);
        mCatalogsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}
```

При первой загрузке RecyclerView все хорошо, я повесил слушателя на holder  и если пользователь тыкает по view у меня загружается второй фрагмент (это код из активности)

```
@Override
public void openCatalog(UUID catalogId) {
    ProductsFragment fragment = ProductsFragment.newInstance(catalogId);

    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Он нормальльно отрабатывает. Проблема возникает когда я жму кнопку "back". У меня загружается первый фрагмент но при этом RecyclerView пустой и я получаю сообщение в андроидмониторе:

No adapter attached; skipping layout

Собственно что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить строку `mCatalogsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` перед `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` в коде первого фрагмента и скажите, что получится.

Comment: @post_zeew - помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сообщение `No adapter attached; skipping layout` говорит о том, что для `RecyclerView` не задан адаптер, то есть `RecyclerView` не связан ни с какими данными.

Когда Вы возвращаетесь к первому фрагменту, получается такая ситуация, что `mAdapter != null` и Вы не связываете `RecyclerView` с данными.

Для решения этой проблемы необходимо строку:

```
mCatalogsRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

вынести из блока `if {...} else {...}` и сэтить адаптер внезависимости от условия `mAdapter == null`.

Comment: А вынести как из блока if..else? Ведь тогда получится сначало вызов notifyDataSetChanged а затем привязка адаптера.

Comment: @plesser, Ну сделайте два блока `if`, это уже не так критично.

Comment: Ок, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Обнуляй адаптер в onDestroyView :

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    realm.close();
    adapter = null;
}
```

Comment: тоже вариант...